# Assign a range to a range variable using ActiveCell.Offset functions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to offset from the current active cell in Excel to define a range and assign it to a variable, so that I can then change some of its properties. This does not work:

```
Public Sub tester()
    Dim myRange As Range
    myRange = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 7))
    myRange.Font.Color = RGB(200, 100, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

In the debugger:

[image]

Although this does work:

```
Public Sub tester()
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 7)).Font.Color = RGB(200, 100, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

What's going on here? Isn't myRange a range? It doesn't seem to want to assign. How do I perform this kind of operation that is, putting a range into a variable and then using that variable to reference it?

Comment: Missing the [`Set` keyword](https://www.homeandlearn.org/the_set_keyword.html).

Comment: ^ literally what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @BigBen Easy as pie. Make it an answer and I'll award it.

Comment: Eh - maybe self-answer?... got other fish to fry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment does not contain the "Set" operator I am reliably informed. This will work:

```
Public Sub tester()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 7))
    myRange.Font.Color = RGB(200, 100, 0)
End Sub
```